# How can I configure multiple MaaS environments for juju?

Tags: juju, maas, hadoop, cassandra

i've realized a vMaaS with 3 vnodes where i deployed juju-gui (node1) and openstack in the other 2 nodes (node2,node3). These last ones at moment are in ready status on vMaaS. Then i've added other vnodes to vMaaS to deploy Cassandra and hadoop, i've already added a new maas environment on environments.yaml called it maassvr02. But every time i try to bootstrap the new one, juju makes the boot of node3 and not the new vnodes. 
my question is:

which is the right way to realize multiple juju environment like that? thanks a lot.

the solution is to run the following commands:

```
$: juju sync-tools -e maassvr02
$: juju bootstrap -e maassvr02 --to node4.maas --debug
```

then i've added also the node5.maas

Comment: Can you post your environments.yaml (obscure the secrets) and share the command you're running to bootstrap?

Comment: the configuration file is that:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/7828920/  and the commands used to bootstrap the new environment are these http://paste.ubuntu.com/7828916/

Comment: Thanks, those both seem reasonable (note the -e is unnecessary if you've "juju switch"ed). You say that you've installed openstack on nodes 2 and 3, but they are in Ready state? That is inconsistent, if you have services deployed they should be Started, not Ready. Did you use Juju to deploy to nodes 2 and 3?

Comment: hi, i deployed Openstack via juju on nodes 2-3 when their status was in allocated, at the end of the procedure i tested Openstack dashboard and then decided to stop the nodes in ready status via MaaS to create another juju environment with new vnodes.

Comment: Stopping a node is essentially powering it off. It should only be done when you no longer need the data or services on that machine. It sounds like MAAS and Juju are behaving as designed

Comment: I've resolved that in this way: after to add the new environment i run these commands http://paste.ubuntu.com/7830809/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP posted:

> I've resolved that in this way: after to add the new environment i run these commands:

```
juju sync-tools -e maassvr02
juju bootstrap -e maassvr02 --to node4.maas --debug
```